# I have to send my broken Tablet back, what should I do with my data?

Tags: data-leakage, amazon

The display of my Fire Tablet is broken, so I cannot do anything on the device. A member of support told me, when I remove the Tablet from my Amazon account via web browser, all data will be removed. But I am still afraid of data leakage. What should I do?

According to another support member removing my tablet from my account, it will not be reseted.

I removed all internal storage, that is accessable through PC.

I found a workaround: Connecting it to my PC, taking a screen shot and viewing it on my PC. Than tapping on something, taking a screen shot and so on. This way I could reset the device.

Comment: I see your concern, its difficult, I would not send it back. unless you can encrypt the device before you send it?

Comment: you can encrypt the kindle fire and then wipe it - would that suffice?

Comment: [What condition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5EnDY4IFvA) do you have to return it in?

Comment: @Jedi I think, when I destroy it, I won't get a new one

Comment: To be sure, you can fill it with big files e.g. movies so all previous data is over-written and cannot be recovered with specialized tools. After you got it back, encrypt it.

Comment: @Aria I won't get it back. I get a new one